# icecream: how can I make icecream to not name the files starting with a number

Tags: linux, debian

icecream names the files like this : nnnn-artist-songtitle.

How can I change it to : artist-songtitle

I suppose its something like

`icecream --name="......"`,

but I cant find a way. The man page I have shows this

icecream/1.3
usage: icecream [options] URL [URL...]

```
options:
  -h, --help          print this message
  -q, --quiet         no printouts
  -v, --verbose       be verbose
  -t, --tracks        split into tracks when saving
  --name=NAME         save stream to file NAME. Format codes
                      are replaced as in the date command.
  --stop=N[units]     stop download after N (kb, mb, min, songs)
  --user-agent=AGENT  identify as AGENT stead of icecream/1.3
  --stdout            output stream to stdout (implies quiet)
  --sync              sync mpeg audio
  --debug             turn on debugging
```

I know I can use a filename with today's date as output

```
icecream -q --name 'radio_%Y_%m_%d' http://radio.com/playlist.pls
```

I suppose there are such %-codes also for artist and song title, but it looks like they are undocumented, and that's exactly my question

PLEASE HELP.

Comment: According to the man page it accepts only flags available in the `date` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`icecream` is a perl script so we can check if there really is an undocumented %-code as you suspect. Just open the script and have a look how it's done (line `1135` in v1.3):

```
$config->{name} = strftime($config->{name},localtime(time));
```

So only thing it does when you use `--name` option is a call to POSIX function `strftime()` which [as you can see here](http://search.cpan.org/~dexter/POSIX-strftime-GNU-0.02/lib/POSIX/strftime/GNU.pm) won't contain any tags for artist or song title.

Why your files are named `nnnn-artist-songtitle` can be found on line `647`:

```
my $fn = $trackid . $context->{title};
```

Seemingly it gets title from the playlist and prepends a unique id. If you don't want to have the id in the name, you could simply remove it and keep just `my $fn = $context->{title};`

This will name the files as they are named in the playlist. But after this change uniqueness is not granted, so some files could get overwritten. I suggest making a copy of `icecream` script and using the modified version only on playlists where you are sure the names are unique.